# Invalid conversion from runtime type String to Double

Tags: apex, string, casting, double

**Background**

I am getting this error:

> Invalid conversion from runtime type String to Double

On this line of code:

```
line.put(targetField, (Double)fieldValue);
```

The variable `fieldValue` is of type `String` and contains the value `4`

The variable `targetField` is of type `String` and contains the value `QUANTITY`

The above code is trying to set of the value of `4` on the `QUANTITY` field of the `QuoteLineItem` object.

**Questions**

1. Why is my cast not working in this `QuoteLineItem.QUANTITY` field?
2. How can I successfully cast the String?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are going to cast a variable, you’re most likely doing what’s known as a downcast. This means that you’re taking the Object and casting it into a more “specific” type of Object. Here’s an example:

```
Object aSentenceObject = 'This is just a regular sentence';
String aSentenceString = (String)aSentenceObject;
```

also you can use "upcast"

```
String aSentenceString = 'This is just another regular sentence';
Object aSentenceObject = (Object)aSentenceString;
```

as you can see from example, for doing casting you have to have inheritance between classes. Double and String don't have such inheritance.

---

use [Double.valueOf](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_double.htm) method

```
line.put(targetField, Double.valueOf(fieldValue));
```

Comment: Great. Thank you for updating your answer with the explanation of why :)